# How to set a custom color for the popup of action items, including of the overflow menu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, popupmenu, overflow-menu

### Background

I'm working on adding some material design style for an app, so I've chosen a different color for the action bar and status bar.

### The problem

For this, the theme of the app is of "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar", and added this to hide the action bar as I need to handle it as a toolbar:

theme I've used:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

layout I've used :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/activity_app_list__toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

code:

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    _toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.activity_app_list__toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
    }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

and for some reason I get this behavior:

1. sub menus of action items and of the overflow item are black.
2. when clicking the search action item , the overflow item there is white.

I'd like to customize those popup menus so that they will be consistent.

### What I've tried

I've tried using this:

```
<item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>

...
<style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu.Overflow">
</style>
```

But it didn't help at all.

### The question

Does anyone know how to handle this? Is this a bug in the support library?

For me it looks this way, so I've reported about it [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172448), including a sample project.

Comment: You mean you want a Light Overflow menu while the others are in Dark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize overflow menu with the `popupTheme` attribute:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/triple_height_toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

---

Original answer was missing some points:

First, the toolbar should have:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"/>
```

For light popup, use this:

```
  <style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarTheme.Light</item>
    <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.ActionBarTheme.Light" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FFffffff</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
  </style>
```

For dark popup, use this:

```
  <style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarTheme.Dark</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.ActionBarTheme.Dark" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FFffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFffffff</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: This one worked. Any idea about the cause of this inconsistent behavior ? Also, suppose I want them all to be black, what should be done? And does it also work for sub menus ?

Comment: The new toolbar uses `app:popupTheme` to style overflow menu, there is no inconsistency. If you want black overflow menu you should use `@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat`. It should also style sub menu.

Comment: using the "@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat" doesn't work, as it won't affect the overflow menu when using the actionMode (for me it's still white in this case). This is why I call it inconsistency, because one overflow menu is dark and another is light.

Comment: You can try to use `@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark`

Comment: Still black for overflow of search action item, yet white for actionMode. I also wonder how to change the color myself. I couldn't even find how to change the color of the text-caret of the search item.

Comment: Can you post the screenshots of the two menus?

Comment: I think I've found the solution. just use "actionBarPopupTheme" . May I edit your answer? I will first perform some more tests when I get back home

Comment: Sure if `actionBarPopupTheme` resolve the issue, you can edit the answer without any problem.

Comment: Done. BTW, as I've read somewhere, it's ok to use "android:theme" instead (for the toolbar).