# Change the theme of overflow menu during ActionMode ActionBar - actionBarPopupTheme and popupTheme doesn't work

Tags: android

By referring to [Styling ActionMode ActionBar in Android 5.0 Lollipop (with AppCompat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992936/styling-actionmode-actionbar-in-android-5-0-lollipop-with-appcompat) and [How to set a custom color for the popup of action items, including of the overflow menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148070/how-to-set-a-custom-color-for-the-popup-of-action-items-including-of-the-overfl), I tend to change the overflow menu to light theme (Black text, white background)

I use

```
<style name="Widget.ActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <!-- RED COLOR -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/dummy</item>

    <!-- Hope to get light theme overflow menu. But doesn't work. -->
    <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="android:popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
</style>
```

But, I'm still getting a dark theme menu.

[image]

Any idea what went wrong? Note, changing the background of ActionMode `ActionBar` to red works well.

---

### Extra info

My app theme is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`, with `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>`, so that when I `startSupportActionMode`, the ActionMode `ActionBar` will cover the `Toolbar`.

The following is the style used by my app.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Noteplus.Base.Brown" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <!-- Custom action mode style -->
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/Widget.ActionMode</item>

    <!-- For action mode -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

For displaying ActionMode ActionBar, I'm using this technique - [Display ActionMode over Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483778/display-actionmode-over-toolbar)

Comment: his toolbar theme is `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` what is yours?

Comment: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed from

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Noteplus.Base.Brown" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/Widget.ActionMode</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

to

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Noteplus.Base.Brown" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/Widget.ActionMode</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

solve the problem. (Not exactly sure the reason behind)

Comment: I know why. If you dive into the parent themes, actually `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` extending `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`, when `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` has a property `<item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>`, so maybe you don't need to change the parent theme. What you want to do is just move your `<item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>` from `Widget.ActionMode` to `Theme.Noteplus.Base.Brown`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="PopupMenu"  parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
```

This makes the text black:

```
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">#000</item>
```

This changes the background color

```
<item name="android:popupBackground">#fff</item>
```

Please let me know if anything changed!

Comment: I'm taking on Action Mode ActionBar only. Your change will affect entire app background color.

Comment: I updated the answer dont forget to add it to your main theme

Answer (score 0):

```
 <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>

 <style name="PopupMenu.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/popup_menu</item>
</style>
```

keyword "overflow". You just need different menu (actionOverflowMenuStyle).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).